# MATLAB code for adding two signals for different time intervals

Tags: matlab

I have got two sine waves shifted 180 degrees from each other. I would like to create another signal from these two, but for that I have to add separate intervals separately and the resultant should be continuous as well.

Here are two sine waves:

[image: Two sine waves]

```matlab
t = 0:0.00001:0.02;

w= 2*pi*50;
ma = 0.8*sin(w*t);
mb = 0.8*sin(w*t-pi);
```

Now I want to create another signal `mcm`. For an interval "0 to 0.005 (quarter cycle)" I want `mcm = 1 + ma`. For interval "0.005 to 0.01" I want `mcm = 1 + mb`.

And likewise for the other two quarters.

How do we go about doing it?

Comment: You are not doing GUI development, and you are not creating standalone MATLAB executables. The tags [tag:matlab-guide] and [tag:matlab-coder] are in no way related to your question. Likewise, [tag:signals] is used for process interrupt signals. Please read tag descriptions more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit after the question was changed in the comment below*

Given the need to generalise this to multiple cycles (note the addition of the user defined input `n` = number of cycles), here is what I would suggest.

Firstly, each function has to be explicitly defined. Secondly, for each point along the length of `t`, the function that needs to be used at that data point needs to be (explicitly) defined.

Thus in the code below, `functions` and `functionOrder` are used to set the functions to be used, and the order/frequency in which they are to be used.

In the `Calculate mcm` section, a variable `ind` is used to iterate over the output, and select the function to be used at each point.

```
% User inputs
f = 50;
n = 3; % number of cycles
inc = 0.00001; % increment

% Preliminaries
t_interval = 1/f;
t = 0:inc:t_interval*n; 
t = t(1:end-1);

w = 2*pi*f;
ma = 0.8*sin(w*t);
mb = 0.8*sin(w*t-pi);

% Define mcm
f1 = @(ii) -1 - mb(ii);
f2 = @(ii)  1 - ma(ii);
f3 = @(ii) -1 + mb(ii);
f4 = @(ii)  1 - mb(ii);
functions = {f1, f2, f3, f4};
functionOrder = [1 2 3 4];

% Calculate mcm
ind = repmat(functionOrder, round(t_interval/inc)/length(functionOrder), 1);
ind = reshape(ind, numel(ind), 1);
ind = repmat(ind, n, 1);

mcm = zeros(size(ind));
for ii = 1:length(ind)
    mcm(ii) = functions{ind(ii)}(ii);
end

% Plot
figure; plot(t,ma);
hold on; plot(t,mb);
plot(t, mcm);
```

================================================

*Previous answer to the simpler question, without the need for generalisability*

The way I would approach this would be a compromise between ease of use in the current situation and ease of replication/dynamism as the example changes.

First create a variable that is in indicator of where `ma` should be used and `mb` should be used. Note that using 0 and 1 makes future steps easier: if you had more functions to utilise in this piecewise operation, the construction of this indicator would have to be different.

```
ind = zeros(size(t)); %indicator
ind(t >= 0.000 && t < 0.005) = 1;
ind(t >= 0.010 && t <=0.015) = 1;
```

Then, the addition of `ma` and `mb` is relatively straightforward.

```
mcm = 1 + ind.*ma + (1-ind).*mb;
```

[Note that this follows the mathematical formulation described in the text, but the resulting curve is not continuous. I do not see a way to do this so that `ma` and `mb` alternate every quarter cycle and the curve is also continuous.]

Comment: I did the same using the following code 


`t = 0:0.00001:t_interval;
f = 50;
t_interval = 1/f;
w= 2*pi*50;
ma = 0.8*sin(w*t);
mb = 0.8*sin(w*t-pi);

plot(t,ma);

mcm1 = -1-mb;
mcm1(t>t_interval/4) = 0;

mcm2 = 1-ma;
mcm2 (t<t_interval/4) =0;
mcm2(t>t_interval/2)=0;

mcm3 = -1+mb;
mcm3(t<t_interval/2)=0;
mcm3(t>(3*t_interval)/4)=0;
mcm4 = 1-mb;
mcm4(t<(3*t_interval)/4) = 0;
mcm4 (t>t_interval)=0;

hold on 
plot(t,mb);
hold on 
`


But as you said I cannot do it for every cycle . I am able to do it 1 cycle only . I want help with generalising it .